# unexpected output using regex on sed in unix

Tags: regex, unix, sed

```
echo "abc123" | sed s/[a-z]*/TEXT/g
```

For the above command output is

```
TEXT1TEXT2TEXT3TEXT
```

should not it be `TEXTTEXTTEXT123`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using quantifier `*` which matches 0 or more of `[a-z]`. First it matches `abc` and due to use of `g` (global) mode it matches empty text after `1`, `2`, `3` as well.

However if you tweak your regex by removing `*` by using;

```
echo "abc123" | sed 's/[a-z]/TEXT/g'
```

then you wil get:

```
TEXTTEXTTEXT123
```

Comment: Thanks,
but when i execute 
echo "abc123" | grep --color '[a-z]*'
it gives
abc123 (and only abc is colored ).

Comment: How do you think `grep` will color the empty matches after `1, 2, 3`?

Comment: what i am not able to understand is 
why the command 
echo "abc123" | sed s/[a-z]*/TEXT/g

it giving an output with the word TEXT in between the numbers.

Comment: That I've explained in my answer. `*` means 0 or more, hence it is matching empty strings after `1, 2, 3` as well. See the difference with `echo "abc123" | sed -E 's/[a-z]+/TEXT/g'` i.e. `+` instead of `*`